# How to set the value in text view getting from database in android?

Tags: java, android

I am storing the values based on the position in Sqlite database

I am retrieving the value from data base and the value is showing correct.But  when I display the value in text-view it becomes zero.

Please help.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class BabyWearAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> p_id;
    ArrayList<String> p_name;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> imageId;
    ArrayList<String> wash_v;
    ArrayList<String> dry_v;
    ArrayList<String> iron_v;
    Typeface tf;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    Intent i;
    float washItemCount = 0.0f;
    String iconName;
    Vector<BasketDO> vecBasket = new Vector<BasketDO>();
    int countVal1, countVal2, countVal3;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    int KEY, pid;
    String TNAME;
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> launDry = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> stremIron = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dryCleans = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> mListLaundry = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();

    public BabyWearAdapter(Context con, ArrayList<String> pid,
            ArrayList<String> pname, ArrayList<String> pimg,
            ArrayList<String> wash, ArrayList<String> dry,
            ArrayList<String> iron) {
        p_id = pid;
        context = con;
        p_name = pname;
        imageId = pimg;
        wash_v = wash;
        dry_v = dry;
        iron_v = iron;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName",
                context.MODE_APPEND);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageId.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @SuppressLint({ "UseValueOf", "ViewHolder" })
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic, parent, false);

        final LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        final LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ll2);
        final LinearLayout ll3 = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ll3);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        final TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        final TextView tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        tv1.setText(wash_v.get(position));
        tv2.setText(iron_v.get(position));
        tv3.setText(dry_v.get(position));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageId.get(position), img);

        dbHandler = new DBHandler(context);

        int pid = Integer.parseInt(p_id.get(position));
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
        i = new Intent("com.example.safewash");
        final  TextView tvVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
        final TextView  tvVal1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvVal1);
        final  TextView tvVal2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvVal2);
        ll1.setTag(p_id.get(position));
        ll2.setTag(p_id.get(position));
        ll3.setTag(p_id.get(position));


        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from babywear_tbl where pid =" + pid,
                null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {


                String countVal1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("laundry_item"));
                String countVal2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dry_item"));
                String countVal3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("iron_item"));

                final int count1 =Integer.parseInt(countVal1);
                final int count2 =Integer.parseInt(countVal2);
                final int count3 =Integer.parseInt(countVal3);

                tvVal.setText("" + count1);
                tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





                System.out.println("The Value one is "+countVal1);
                Log.i("Count Val One",""+countVal1);

        }
        try {

            int temp = launDry.get(Integer.parseInt(ll1.getTag().toString()
                    .trim()));
            int val = temp + 1;
            tvVal.setText("" + val);
            tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tvVal.setText("0");
        }

        try {

            int temp = stremIron.get(Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString()
                    .trim()));
            int val = temp + 1;
            tvVal1.setText("" + val);
            tvVal1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tvVal1.setText("0");
        }

        try {

            int temp = dryCleans.get(Integer.parseInt(ll1.getTag().toString()
                    .trim()));
            int val = temp + 1;
            tvVal2.setText("" + val);
            tvVal2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tvVal2.setText("0");
        }

        ll1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                int count = 0;

                String washItem = wash_v.get(position);
                int washItems = Integer.parseInt(washItem);

                if (washItems != 0) {
                    int colorStart = Color.LTGRAY;
                    int colorEnd = 0;

                    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,
                            "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
                    animator.setDuration(800);
                    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    animator.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animator.start();

                    washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);

                    tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    count = Integer.parseInt(tvVal.getText().toString());
                    countVal1 = ++count;

                    i.putExtra("washItemCount", washItemCount);
                    i.putExtra("countVal1", countVal1);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);
                    try {

                        int temp = launDry.get(Integer.parseInt(ll1.getTag()
                                .toString().trim()));

                        temp++;
                        launDry.put(Integer.parseInt(ll1.getTag().toString()
                                .trim()), temp);

                        long id = dbHandler.insertBabyWearValues(Integer
                                .parseInt(ll1.getTag().toString().trim()),
                                countVal1, countVal2, countVal3);

                        if (id == -1) {
                            long updateid = dbHandler.updateBabyWear(countVal1,
                                    countVal2, countVal3);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "ID value" + updateid,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "ID value" + id,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Appconstants.laundryHashmap = launDry;

                        int val = temp + 1;
                        tvVal.setText("" + val);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        launDry.put(Integer.parseInt(ll1.getTag().toString()
                                .trim()), 0);
                        tvVal.setText("" + 1);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        ll2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                int count = 0;
                String washItem = iron_v.get(position);

                washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);
                int washItems = Integer.parseInt(washItem);
                if (washItems != 0) {
                    int colorStart = Color.LTGRAY;
                    int colorEnd = 0;
                    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,
                            "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
                    animator.setDuration(800);
                    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    animator.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animator.start();
                    washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);

                    tvVal1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    count = Integer.parseInt(tvVal1.getText().toString());
                    countVal2 = ++count;
                    // tvVal1.setText("" + countVal2);
                    i.putExtra("washItemCount", washItemCount);
                    i.putExtra("countVal2", countVal2);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);

                    try {

                        int temp = stremIron.get(Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag()
                                .toString().trim()));
                        temp++;
                        stremIron.put(Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString()
                                .trim()), temp);
                        long id = dbHandler.insertBabyWearValues(Integer
                                .parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString().trim()),
                                countVal1, countVal2, countVal3);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "ID value" + id,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (id == -1) {
                            long updateid = dbHandler.updateBabyWear(countVal1,
                                    countVal2, countVal3);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "ID value" + updateid,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        Appconstants.ironHashmap = stremIron;
                        int val = temp + 1;
                        tvVal1.setText("" + val);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        stremIron.put(Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString()
                                .trim()), 0);
                        tvVal1.setText("" + 1);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        ll3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                int count = 0;
                String washItem = dry_v.get(position);
                washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);
                int washItems = Integer.parseInt(washItem);
                if (washItems != 0) {
                    int colorStart = Color.LTGRAY;
                    int colorEnd = 0;

                    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,
                            "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
                    animator.setDuration(800);
                    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    animator.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animator.start();

                    washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);

                    tvVal2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    count = Integer.parseInt(tvVal2.getText().toString());
                    countVal3 = ++count;
                    // tvVal2.setText("" + countVal3);
                    i.putExtra("washItemCount", washItemCount);
                    i.putExtra("countVal3", countVal3);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);
                    try {

                        int temp = dryCleans.get(Integer.parseInt(ll3.getTag()
                                .toString().trim()));
                        temp++;
                        dryCleans.put(Integer.parseInt(ll3.getTag().toString()
                                .trim()), temp);
                        long id = dbHandler.insertBabyWearValues(Integer
                                .parseInt(ll3.getTag().toString().trim()),
                                countVal1, countVal2, countVal3);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "ID value" + id,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (id == -1) {
                            long updateid = dbHandler.updateBabyWear(countVal1,
                                    countVal2, countVal3);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "ID value" + updateid,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap = dryCleans;
                        int val = temp + 1;
                        tvVal2.setText("" + val);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        dryCleans.put(Integer.parseInt(ll3.getTag().toString()
                                .trim()), 0);
                        tvVal2.setText("" + 1);
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here the point is I wrote this logic adapter i.e getView().

Comment: Are you sure that your count1 variable  is not 0??

Comment: yes yar i debugg also

Comment: Just print System.out.println(count1); before tvVal.setText("" + count1); and let me know what is the result on console.

Comment: Any exceptions ? Share your log.

Comment: are those values in point system like 0.89/0.55 then the final value will become zero because you are using Integer.parseInt to convert those values. You can directly show those values in textview without converting them in integer

Comment: ok yar just a minute

Comment: System.out(20081): The Value one is 3

Answer (score 0):

This can be because your value may be in decimal and during parsing it into integer it is converted to 0 if number is below 1 i.e. 0.88 etc

change your code from

```
String countVal1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("laundry_item"));
String countVal2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dry_item"));
String countVal3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("iron_item"));

int count2 =Integer.parseInt(countVal2);
int count3 =Integer.parseInt(countVal3);
int count1 =Integer.parseInt(countVal1);

tvVal.setText("" + count1);
tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Changed code

```
String countVal1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("laundry_item"));
String countVal2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dry_item"));
String countVal3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("iron_item"));

tvVal.setText(countVal1);
tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You can directly show your value into textview without converting them into integer and then showing with string addition.

Please check and let me know if it helps.

**Edit:**

After checking your code I found that following lines may create problem in your code which in turn converting your value to zero in text view they are

```
try {

            int temp = launDry.get(Integer.parseInt(ll1.getTag().toString()
                    .trim()));
            int val = temp + 1;
            tvVal.setText("" + val);
            tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tvVal.setText("0"); // Here you are setting it to zero
        }

        try {

            int temp = stremIron.get(Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString()
                    .trim()));
            int val = temp + 1;
            tvVal1.setText("" + val);
            tvVal1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tvVal1.setText("0"); // Here you are setting it to zero
        }
```

These try blocks is some how throwing exception which in turn in catch block value of your text view is turning to zero. Please check your try block code, why they are throwing exception.

**Edit 2:** 
In case if your `HashMap` "`launDry`" or "`stremIron`" does not contains key which you are passing by `Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString().trim())` then it will return null and integer cannot consist null. I believe exception is thrown in this case. Please check again.

**Edit 3:**
Solution as requested

```
try {

        String temp = stremIron.get(Integer.parseInt(ll2.getTag().toString()
                    .trim()));
        if(temp != null){
           int val = Integer.parseInt(temp) + 1;
           tvVal1.setText("" + val);
           tvVal1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         tvVal1.setText("0"); // Here you are setting it to zero
     }
```

Comment: i try in that case also the value getting from the database is correct and that value is setted in textview is zero

Comment: Please add your full source code into question. It is really important to analyze whole code.

Comment: if i remove the lines the values is not setting the correct positions

Comment: You do not have to remove these line just have to check that the key is available in hashmap or not. You can get the value of try in String then check if its not null then do the parsing thing.

Comment: can utell me the solution how can i do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89344/discussion-between-abhinav-singh-maurya-and-manikanta-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are setting the value of a text field from non-ui thread.
If you don't set the value for textField in UI thread it will not change.
Change the lines:

```
   int count1 =Integer.parseInt(countVal1);
                tvVal.setText("" + count1);
```

to

```
 final int count1 =Integer.parseInt(countVal1);
        runOnUiThread(new new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            tvVal.setText("" + count1);
                        }
                    });
```

Or if you can't access runOnUiThread, then use this postToUI method:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

public class UITools {

    public static void postToUI(Runnable r) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: check the other soultion i've provided for running on UI therad.

Answer (score 0):

Try your query like this and see whats the output:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from babywear_tbl where pid ='" + pid+"'",
                null);
```

that's a single quote like this `pid='"+pid+"'",null);` don't put any spaces

Comment: in the catch statement put some value like -1 here tvVal1.setText("-1"); if the value in the txtVal1 again comes to be -1 then you are getting an exception

Comment: the value become zeroonly

Comment: i am not getting any exception

Comment: try using Integer.valueOf(countVal1);

Comment: try removing that final keywords if you are not getting an errors after removing it  just a trial and error way